# Meteor.js when calling Foo.update(id,{conditions}) removes document fields

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a tasks collection in the meteor application.
I want to push a task from "todo" to "doing" and to "done" `statuses`

I've got them in lists with their ids in DOM

Created a meteor method to update a Task, called the method, did not work. Nothing happened, the task won't update.

So, I tried calling the Task.update method direct

```
 Meteor.methods({
    create : function(json){Task.insert(json);},
    update : function(id, conditions){Task.update(id, {$set : conditions});}
  });

Template.todo.events({
    'click .submit' : function(){
      console.log("event called",this._id);
      //Meteor.call('update',(this._id, {'status':'doing'}));
      Task.update(this._id, {'status':'doing'});
    }
  });
```

When           Task.update(this._id, {'status':'doing'});

is called. The description field in collection goes empty and only the status field is updated.

Before Task.update

```
{ "_id" : "er6Rqvdj8P373cPM5", "status" : "doing" , "description" : "work out and eat green chillies"}
```

After `Task.update("er6Rqvdj8P373cPM5",{"status":"done"})`

```
{ "_id" : "er6Rqvdj8P373cPM5", "status" : "done" }
```

while calling `update : function(id, conditions){Task.update(id, {$set : conditions});}`

I'm getting the following error in meteor logs

Exception while invoking method 'update' MongoError: Invalid modifier specified: $set

```
Exception while invoking method 'update' MongoError: Invalid modifier specified: $set
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/otto/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:322:15)
    at _Mongo.update (app/packages/mongo-livedata/mongo_driver.js:269:12)
    at _.each.Meteor.Collection.(anonymous function) [as update] (app/packages/mongo-livedata/collection.js:354:32)
    at Meteor.methods.update (app/alacrity.js:39:45)
    at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method.exception (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:593:30)
    at _.extend.withValue (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:31:17)
    at app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:592:46
    at _.extend.withValue (app/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:31:17)
    at _.extend.protocol_handlers.method (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:591:37)
    at _.extend.processMessage.processNext (app/packages/livedata/livedata_server.js:484:43)
    - - - - -
    at Object.exports.toError (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/utils.js:108:11)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:477:24)
    at g (events.js:192:14)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:130:25)
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:517:20)
    at MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:127:5)
    at Server.connect.connectionPool.on.server._serverState (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:476:22)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:96:17)
    at _connect (/Users/otto/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/405d21f01568c045554ee5b99d2bea88a5249feb/.npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:175:13)
```

While meteor docs say:

```
// mark my first message as "important"
Messages.update(myMessages[0]._id, {$set: {important: true}});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_user

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you've found the error until now, but I'm posting this for others that might face the same problem.

This line has extra brackets:

```
Meteor.call('update',(this._id, {'status':'doing'}));
```

It should be like this:

```
Meteor.call('update',this._id, {'status':'doing'});
```

If you ever get this message:

```
MongoError: Invalid modifier specified: $set
```

The problem will probably be with what's right next to $set. Which in the case above is "undefined".

Happened to me today :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends what modifier you're using & that might trigger this error.

Basically if you use:

```
Task.update(this._id, {'status':'doing'});
```

It will set the document with `this._id` as `{status: 'doing'}`

If you use `$set` it will set only those fields specified:

```
Task.update(this._id, { $set: {'status': 'doing'}});
```

You also don't have to use a method & can do it directly on the client. More details on how to use $set at the [mongodb docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set)

Comment: I'm doing this now

`      Meteor.call('update',(String(this._id), {$set : {status:'doing'}}));


    update : function(id, conditions){Tasks.update(String(id), conditions);}

and I'm getting:

`Exception while invoking method 'update' Error: Invalid modifier. Modifier must be an object.
    at _Mongo.update (app/packages/mongo-livedata/`